# Notifications when iPhone is turned off or app is uninstalled

Tags: ios, notifications

I was recently asked questions related to Notifications in an interview :

1. What **happens** to the notifications when the iPhone is turned off
2. What **happens** to the notifications when the user has uninstalled my application

I know there are already some questions related to Notifications but none of them explains **what really happens to all those notifications** like where are they stored or what happens to them for the time being but what they ask or others answer is that *how to still get the notification* which is not really my question

Comment: Apple explains this on their site in the Push Notifications section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When the phone is turned off, the notifications will remain on APNS for the expiry time and APNS will try to deliver it until it expires. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns) and search for `apns-expiration`
2. If the app is uninstalled, you will get an error on server side that the device token to which the notifications is sent is not valid any more.

You must read the docs carefully. It is all mentioned there.

Comment: But how does the server(APN) gets notified that the app has been uninstalled ? Like is there a message sent to the APN when the app is uninstalled ?

Comment: There could be various ways. Not sure of the exact implementation. There could be a constant task running on phones that could tell the server that the user has uninstalled the app or the user might try to first send the notification to phone and then the phone tells that this app is not installed.

Comment: Sounds Fair. One last question, i forgot to add it to the original question , just now clicked. What happens when the user has **not uninstalled the app** but has just set the notifications turned off, what happens then? Will it be like case 2 that you answered or somewhat different ?